# ¿Se entiende en Hispanoamérica "tengo que ir" como "tengo que ir al baño"?

Tags: modismos, hispanoamérica

Mi hijo mayor ha descubierto en YouTube Kids vídeos de una serie de Disney Junior que en inglés se titula "[Nina needs to go!](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3747354/?ref_=nv_sr_1)". La serie va sobre una niña que ha dejado de usar pañales recientemente, pero está cada dos por tres con ganas de ir al baño en las situaciones más insospechadas, y la carrera hasta el baño es poco menos que una odisea.

He visto vídeos de la serie en español de España y en español de Hispanoamérica. En la versión de España la serie se titula "Nina ya es mayor", y en los episodios la frase que repite es "tengo que ir al baño".

Sin embargo, en la versión de Hispanoamérica la serie traduce literalmente el título original como "Nina tiene que ir", y lo que dice cada dos por tres es "tengo que ir" y "de verdad tengo que ir". Incluso la frase que repite siempre al final de cada episodio es "no debes seguir si tienes que ir".

¿Se entiende en Hispanoamérica la expresión "tengo que ir" como "tengo que ir al baño"? ¿O es simplemente que tradujeron la expresión original de forma literal? Si se entiende, ¿es algo generalizado o solo en determinados países? ¿Se entiende en cualquier contexto o solo cuando hay niños pequeños involucrados?

Comment: Esta distinción es definitivamente regional. He escuchado de todas formas algo del estilo *tengo que ir* pero en realidad de uso frecuente en mi país.

Comment: I think can see a whole new question on the horizon - how do you say in Spanish I need to go for a ... if you are an adult?

Comment: @mdewey - A fun question.  Go for it!

Comment: @Charlie - Si en el contexto alguien me dice, "Tengo que ir al baño", y más tarde me dice, "De veras tengo que ir", se va a entender de qué se trata.  Pero sin el contexto, pues no, no se entendería, por lo menos en México.  Bottom line: context is everything.

Answer (score 6):

> ¿Se entiende en Hispanoamérica la expresión "tengo que ir" como "tengo que ir al baño"?

No en Colombia, o al menos yo no lo entendería así. Quizá viendo un niño haciendo caras extrañas se entendería fácilmente, pero sin el contexto adecuado no. Ahora, luego de saber a qué se refiere, en un niño encontraría ese uso aceptable, pero en un adulto la frase me resultaría extraña e infantil.

Comment: Indeed it is used only by children in English (in the UK).

Comment: Creo que no se usa en Mexico tampoco.

Comment: @aparente001 Así es. En México si alguien diría "Tengo que ir" uno contestaría con "¿A dónde?"

Comment: @psosuna - Pero un eufemismo que sí funciona, creo, sobre todo en el campo, es "Ahorita vengo."  ¿Te parece?

Comment: @aparente001 yo sí he escuchado algo similar: "Ahora vuelvo que tengo que hacer una vuelta" o "Tengo una diligencia que hacer"

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. Aquí en Colombia los niños tranquilamente dicen "voy al baño". Si alguien dijera "tengo que ir" nadie asumiría nada e inmediatamente respondería "¿ir a dónde?

Answer (score 2):

Considero que es más debido a una traducción literal que a otros motivos. Por regla general si tu dices: "Tengo que ir" y luego no añades nada más la mayoría de la gente te preguntará: "¿Ir a dónde?". Así que lo más probable es que en Hispanoamérica se decidiera traducir de forma literal el título de la serie.  Soy de Madrid.

Comment: Soy español, de Madrid. Sí, debería haber especificado que en mi región se dicen las cosas así.

Comment: apoyo la impresión de que título fue hecho con una traducción literal y una inacabada comprensión del alcance hispanoamericano de ese uso (solo confirmado hasta aquí por algunas regiones de México)

Answer (score 2):

No, no se entiende por si sola la frase de "tengo que ir" por "tengo que ir al baño". En este caso, es utilizada como una abreviación de la oración de algo que ya se sabe.

Como tu, que ya sabes que va a ir al baño por que leíste la sinopsis de la serie o por que ya la viste y sabes a lo que se refiere con "tengo que ir".

> -- ¿Vas a hacer el examen en la escuela?
>
> -- No me gustaría hacerlo, pero tengo que (ir a la escuela).
>
> ---
>
> -- ¿Vas a manejar hasta Guadalajara?
>
> -- Si, no quiero pero tengo que (manejar hasta Guadalajara).

Comment: A mistake I hear frequently in new Spanish speaker is "bla-bla ... pero tengo que."  I assume you omitted the "ir" in your last example sentence through error so I fixed that with an edit.  I wouldn't want new Spanish speakers to get the wrong idea about that from reading your answer.  (Please do a rollback if my edit doesn't feel right.)

Comment: No, no era un error omitir "ir". En México (al menos en el Occidente), se suele omitir el verbo en una respuesta cuando la pregunta ya viene con el verbo incluido, que es como en los ejemplos que puse. No se como se le llame a eso, pero suelo usarlo mucho con mis amigos o incluso hasta con mis papas.

Comment: Bueno pues, perdón, y dime si tienes alguna duda sobre cómo hacer un rollback.  Empieza con oprimir donde dice "edit".

Answer (score 1):

En Chile si se dice "Tengo que ir", de inmediato uno pregunta "¿A dónde?", ya que a la oración por sí sola le faltaría información. Acá los niños dicen "Tengo que ir al baño".

Answer (score -1):

Esto es muy común en Mexico, sobre todo cuando hablamos del lenguaje utilizado por niños.

Es muy normal que en las casas hispanoamericanas a los niños se les prohiba decir palabras con cierto grado de "impureza" que provoca que los niños desarrollen "pudor" al tratar de decir cosas que tienen que ver con ir al baño. Es una especie de autocensura social, donde palabras que tienen que ver con la intimidad personal son cambiadas por "pipi" o "popo".

En los medios de comunicacion hay una sensibilidad muy marcada en cuanto al uso del language.

Así que ... sí, cuando se trata de lenguaje utilizado por niños, sabes que estan omitiendo palabras que les da vergüenza decir.

Recordemos que los niños son criaturas muy sensibles a las observaciones y crítica de los demás.

Comment: No. Esto no es muy común en hispanoamérica. Las otras respuesta lo demuestran. No descarto que sea común en tu entorno por lo que sugiero edites la primera frase por algo que diga en donde realmente es común que tu conozcas porque en hispanoamérica en general no lo es.

Comment: Soy Mexicano, con 6 años viviendo en esados unidos, Con amistades Argentinas y bolivianos, 

de los bolivianos no lo he escuhado, pero si de los argentinos. es entendido en mexico, y tambien por una gran mayoria de latinos viviendo en usa

Comment: Bastaría con que cambiaras la primera frase y adicionaras lo que dices en tu primer comentario sobre su uso en México y que los has escuchado de los argentinos y así sería una respuesta válida. Si dices que es **muy común en hispanoamérica** porque lo usan en 2 de 20 países pues no es correcto. Estoy de acuerdo que el "si" es incluyente, pero **muy común** suena a mayoría y 2 de 20 es minoría. Si la respuesta considerará eso le daría +1. Ojalá la editaras. Saludos.